# Asterisk PAMI QueueStatus Action does not return the queue name, how can I get the queue name with asterisk ami action

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami, freepbx

The Asterisk PAMI QueueStatus Action returns QueueParams Event, that reutrns information about the queue including [Queue, Max, Strategy, Calls, HoldTime, etc..]. But it does not return the queue name/description

Here is the code that I wrote

```
public function queueStatus()
{
 $this->send(new QueueStatusAction());
}
```

And I receive QueueParams Event

```
{"event":"QueueParams","queue":"701","max":"0","strategy":"ringall","calls":"0","holdtime":"0","talktime":"0","completed":"0","abandoned":"0","servicelevel":"60","servicelevelperf":"0.0","servicelevelperf2":"0.0","weight":"0","actionid":"1693735123.62"}
```

As you can see, there is no queue name or description

Answer (score 0):

There is no queue name entity in asterisk.

[image: Output of queue show]

Queue name exists only in PBX management interface. Most common one is FreePBX, for FreePBX queue name can be looked up in queues_description table.

```
MariaDB [asterisk]> select descr from queues_config where extension=501;
+----------------+
| descr          |
+----------------+
| dialed-inbound |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

You also can make it cached in Memcached or no-sql if you are going do that often.

Comment: As per this post, In AMI QueueStatus Action returns the queue name as 
```````
=>Request
Action: QueueStatus

=> Return value example
Response: Success
Message: Queue status will follow

Event: QueueParams
Queue: test_queue
Max: 0
Calls: 4
Holdtime: 2
Completed: 0
Abandoned: 0
ServiceLevel: 0
ServicelevelPerf: 0.0
Weight: 0
````````````````

Comment: Also, I am dealing with multiple servers so I want to keep using the databases to their minimal

Comment: I don't know where you got that. Asterisk do not store name of queue. You can put it in astdb and collect as dbget

Comment: Check  /etc/asterisk/queues_additional.conf  and try get any names in it.